# regular expression to check if every comma is seperated by a space

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write a regular expression to find if every comma is followed by a space or not. If atleast one comma is not followed by a space then it should return true. If all the commas present are definitely followed by space then return false.

Example :`hi, hello are two words. one, two are numbers` this should return false.
`hi, hello are two words. one,two are numbers` this should return true because there is no space after one comma

Comment: it seems like a problem a linear search could also solve. if you want to use a regex, think the opposite way: are there any commas not followed by a space? You can use negative lookaheads for that.

Comment: my context is different. my requirement is to use regex only. but i am not able to get it

Comment: anything to share that you have tried so far?

Comment: nothing useful of my tries :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see if this regex produces any matches: `,(?! )` - In this case it means there is a comma that is not followed by a space. If one exists, then you should return `true`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

`/,[^ ]/g`

Explanation: get all the commas that do not have a space just after it.

For it to return a boolean you need to use the test method for regex in js:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test